# Why do I get FTP "protocol not available" error?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, firewall, ftp, protocols

I have been trying to install Centos 8 on my other Virtual Box - Virtual Machine via the kickstart unattended installation.

But I cannot complete the installation because of the below FTP error.

```
ftp: connect: Protocol not available
```

In fact, this is the output of the commands which show me that TCP protocol is available on port 21;

[image]

I have also made these configurations on my **/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf** file;

[image: /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf]

And this is **/etc/services** file;

[image: /etc/services]

Finally, these are the firewall rules;

[image: firewall]

Comment: What are you doing that's giving that error?

Comment: Please [don't post screenshots of console output](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text), copy-and-paste it into your question with appropriate code formatting instead ...

Comment: I am taking this error whenever I want to make an FTP connection from one virtual machine to another one. By the way, I am using the "Host-only adapter" option on Virtualbox in order to have my own LAN. Regarding the second comment, I know but that was the only way to take these outputs from my virtual machine. Sorry about it.

Comment: If you can open a shell on the client, can you run that netstat command? I think the error could be caused by ftp trying to use IPv6.